# Why Ajax clock goes faster at night?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, time

I have a time clock with ajax and PHP. The time clock will be opened at 7:00 a.m. The displayed time is correct in the afternoon. However, I discover that it displays "11:41" at time 11:30 actually. It goes faster. I don't know what is going wrong. Here is my js code:

```
//Clock
 setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
 function timestamp() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'timestamp.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#timestamp').html(data);
            },
        });
    }
```

Here is PHP code:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
    $timestamp = date('H:i');
    $timestamp2 = date('D, d M Y');
    echo "<div class='timecolumn tc1'>";
    echo $timestamp;
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<div class='timecolumn tc2'>";
    echo $timestamp2;
    echo "<div>";
?>
```

Comment: ha ha. that is impossible you are taking current time in your PHP code.

Comment: Your 11:30 clock is wrong

Comment: Have you looked at the request queue? Maybe they take longer than 1 second to return, so they are queuing up and take longer and longer between request and return so by the time you display the time after many thousands of requests, it's way out.